# How to access a controller from a model using CodeIgntier?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to access a controller, which is located in `application/controller/example.php`, from a model - located in `application/model/users.php`

```
 class Users extends CI_Model {

    //access the example.php controller


   }
```

Who could i accomplish this ?

Comment: What we really need to know is, are you trying to access the controller from the model which called it, or a different controller all together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to ever do that, hence why CodeIgniter cannot do it. You should be accessing everything else from your Controller, not the other way around.

A good old resource from CodeIgniter :)
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: +1 Your controller is the root of the MVC arch. YOu should branch out from the Controller to Models and views. never from models to controllers or views to controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to access an controller from a model. Models (Views, helpers, libraries ect) should all be accessed from controllers. ( Model are used from manipulating data ( usually in database ) )

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the MVC is to have a Model, Viewer and Controller.
In other words the Controller handles the request, the Model gets the data and the Viewer displays something to the user.
The Model is used ONLY to manipulate the data - doesn't matter if it's a database connection or other data resource.

Answer (score 0):

Model is where you store your bussines logic. Controller is where you call things and operate with data. Views are for creating output.

Bassically you can do everything from withing controller, but that is wrong, since it does not gain you any clarity. Try to offload as much as possible to models and views and keep controllers small and readable, well commented.